# create custom image slider in react native

Tags: react-native

hello I am new to react native I have given a task to create an `image slider` as shown in the picture

[image]

I have not found any library matching this design so I want to create a `custom carousel` how can I create this. Any sort of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details as to what is the requirements of this?

Seems like you are trying to create introductory slides in the app.
This plugin is really flexible and customisable. You might want to check this one out.

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-app-intro-slider

Also if you desire to make a custom slider, you can use ScrollView and use the following configuration to the scrollView

```
<ScrollView
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    pagingEnabled={true}
    horizontal={true}
    scrollEventThrottle={16} >
        <View>
            <Text>Screen 1</Text>
        </View>
        <View>
            <Text>Screen 2</Text>
        </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Tag me if you have any more questions regarding this.

Give this article a read to understand it better.

> https://medium.com/backticks-tildes/create-a-custom-app-intro-slider-in-react-native-4308fae83ad1

Comment: its a tutorial not intro slider

Comment: Same thing @KokabShakil 
Introduction slideshow(intro slider) with left and right swipe and tutorial for app usage is one and the same, I believe. That's what I understood from the question you posted.

Please correct me if I am wrong and also be more descriptive as to what you are trying to achieve.

Did you check the plugin whose link I have shared above? Does it meet your requirements?